# How to resize icon by using javascript

Tags: javascript, html

My cursor that is displayed on canvas is a **base64** encoded icon.  So, my assumption is I can not use the `<img>` tag for it, however, I want to scale this icon.  Is there any way doing it?

My HTML piece

```
<canvas style="cursor: url("data:image/x-icon;base64,.....") 0 0, default;"></canvas>
```

Comment: Please supply a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example. http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: It's my understanding you cant "scale" the `cursor`. My suggestion would be to set the cursor to an invisible image, then use a "follow the cursor" technique with a graphic you do have control over the size of. Have a look at this tutorial https://www.kirupa.com/canvas/follow_mouse_cursor.htm

Comment: Your HTML code is invalid.

Comment: My original thoughts was decode base64, and scale the icon by some aalgorithm, and encode it again.  Makes sense?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can size `canvas` elements the same way as every other kind of element, though you should bear in mind that CSS scaling will not affect the coordinates of the canvas. It's generally better practice to use the `width` and `height` *attributes* of the element rather than the style properties.

I'm also not really sure why you think you can't use base64-encoded strings as a src for `<img>` elements -- this is definitely possible, and I believe is performed in an identical fashion as canvases.

I could be wrong as far as what you're trying to do, though -- there are some strange errors in your example, like a `cursor` attribute, and the attribute being defined with a colon instead of an equals, and there being a closing quote for the attribute but no opening quote. I'm also really not sure `0, 0, default` section of the attribute is supposed to represent.

Comment: @Bomin No trouble! Did the answer help you, or is this not what you were asking about?

Comment: not really, I don't really understand your advise.  Since the cursor is in css, how can I assign its `width` and `height`